# No Globals C# Word

Tags: c#, ms-word, vsto, add-in

I have created a Word addin with C#.
Now I would like to Paste a MergeField into the document.
But my problem is I have no Globals in my class.
Is there an other way to paste something into the document, or how do I get Globals in my class?

Comment: Do you develop a document or application level add-in?

Comment: You don't provide a lot of information. A bit of code would help us to assist you more effectively. You also don't mention the "target" where you want to paste. On the assumption that you're working with the current document selection and that the Word.Application object would be wdApp (you can use any name, but I have to choose one since you don't provide any code):  wdApp.Selection.Paste();